# Difference Between Jquery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Anybody please list differences between Jquery & Ajax ?

Comment: What's the difference between table and hammer?

Comment: Have you even googled? Stackoverflow is not Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between ajax and jquery and which one is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better)

Comment: What is difference between PEN and INK... LOL

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a library that assists in doing hundreds of things, not the least of which is "Ajax". Ajax, which originally meant "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML" is nothing more than the asynchronous transmission of data from the client to the server. jQuery makes it *easier* to perform these asynchronous actions.

```
$.post( "/foo", { name: 'Jonathan' }, function( response ) {
    alert( response );
});
```

In the above example I can use jQuery (represented by `$`) to post data to the `/foo` directory on my server. I then handle the server's response as `response`, and when that response is received, I alert it to the user.

This example would qualify as *Ajax*, though jQuery does have an even more versatile respository of power within the `$.ajax` member.

Further Reading: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Just to be precise - it is a **library**

Comment: @Jonathan you have over powered Jon Skeet,this week. :-/

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a JavaScript library providing a range of utility functions for dealing with the browser environment.

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is a methodology of interacting with your server from a web page and updating the page without page refresh.

Asking what the difference between them is, is like asking what the difference is between a boat and tying knots. There may be a vague relationship (in that on boats, you tend to tie knots), but that's it...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a javascript framework. Ajax is "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", and it can be performed easily using jQuery, allowing for javascript to make a web server request without refreshing the website.

Comment: "ajax is a function of jquery" O_o You better read wikipedia before

Comment: @NitinJS: you haven't seen the original answer. After that it has been changed. PS: "only" what?

Comment: The wording was a little off, but jquery does offer functions to execute ajax calls. So, "ajax is a function of jquery" is correct. How else would you put "jQuery.ajax()" into words? Please tell me there is not a function in the jQuery library called ajax, which performs ajax calls. :P

Answer (score 0):

> [**AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is a technique to do an [**XMLHttpRequest**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (out of
>   band Http request) from a web page to the server and send/retrieve
>   data to be used on the web page. AJAX stands for Asynchronous
>   Javascript And XML.  It uses javascript to construct an
>   XMLHttpRequest, typically using different techniques on various
>   browsers.
>
> [**jQuery**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery) ([**website**](http://jquery.com)) is a javascript framework that
>   makes working with the DOM easier by building lots of high level
>   functionality that can be used to search and interact with the DOM. 
>   Part of the functionality of jQuery implements a high-level interface
>   to do AJAX requests.  jQuery implements this interface abstractly,
>   shielding the developer from the complexity of multi-browser support
>   in making the request.

**Same SO Question**: **[what is the difference between ajax and jquery and which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better)**

Hope this helps.