# Difference between Ajax and Jquery-Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

hi i am new to ajax and jquery. i found many tutorials about ajax and jquery. but what is the difference between Ajax and JQuery ajax?   which should i learn? please answer. Thank you

Comment: [here is a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better) 
duplicate question with good answers
 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## **AJAX**

1. AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.
2. AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.
3. AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.
4. Classic web pages, (which do not use AJAX) must reload the entire page if the content should change.

## JQUERY

1. JQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more", JavaScript library.
2. The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website.
3. jQuery takes a lot of common tasks that require many lines of JavaScript code to accomplish, and wraps them into methods that you can call with a single line of code.
4. jQuery also simplifies a lot of the complicated things from JavaScript, like AJAX calls and DOM manipulation.

So you can code in Jquery very easily wherever you need a AJAX technique

Content from W3SCHOOLS

Answer (score 1):

javascript is a script language, jquery is more like a framework, which is build with javascript. i would recommend, before you start to learn Jquery, you should learn the basics of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

They actually do the same thing: they perform an ajax call.
A very very simple definition is: it is a paradigm of programming that allows you to get or post some data in an asynchronous way. An example would be for example for update a small portion of a website instead of reload the entire page.

An extensive resource about Ajax can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Ajax

jQuery ajax (API) is very easy to use and it provides you all you need for keeo going with your work. Anyways if you are curious,  I will suggest you to explore the "plain" javascript ajax call, it is interesting.