# PHP/MySQL - checkboxes of data from db, submission of 2 parametres

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

So, i'm struggling with that for a long time.

I need to make a list with checkboxes from DB like [checkbox of car id and value][brand][model]. Then, we need to choose two cars from list, and two cars are chosen - we should block all unchecked till checked won't be unchecked. Then, we need to sumbit into list.php page two car id of chosen cars. And submission won't be done if one or no car are chosen.

I don get it how to realise. Anybody knows how to solve this? 
And yes: jquery is desirable, ajax is not ('cos i never worked with that and i don't think i need it here because i need just to transmit parametres to another page)

My code

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jdmdb";

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysqli_error());
$con->query("SET NAMES cp1251");
$con->select_db($dbname);
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from cars') or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Tуpe" сontent="tехt/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>JDM Database</title>
        <script src=../js/jquery-2.1.4.js type=text/javascript></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=carlist method=post action="list.php">
        <?
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo '<input type=checkbox name="car_short" value="'.$row['car_short'].' id='.$row['car_short'].'"> '.$row['brand'].' '.$row['model'].' '.$row['spec'].' ('.$row['year'].')<br/>';
            }
            $res = count($rows);  
            echo '<input type=submit value=123>';
        ?>
        </form>
<?            
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/931918/5566036 Maybe this will clear up the AJAX/Jquery for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send array of data to list.php
For that you should use following syntax

```
echo '<input type=checkbox name="car_short[]" value="'.$row['car_short'].' id='.$row['car_short'].'"> '.$row['brand'].' '.$row['model'].' '.$row['spec'].' ('.$row['year'].')<br/>';
```

This will send send $_POST['car_short'] as array of two selected values. And if you want to check number of selected cars after submission then use

```
if(count($_POST['car_short'])<2){// place error;}
```

Else you can use jquery to check how many checkboxes are selected else return false. For that change the form code like this

```
<form method=post action="list.php" onSubmit="check();">
```

and check function will be

```
function check(){
   var n = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
   return n>1;
}
```

Note: Please note the method the exact code may not work properly since i misspelled variables